# Is my installation of Xcode correct?

Tags: xcode

I recently downloaded an Xcode 4.4 DMG file in Apple's Developer site and then opened it and ran Xcode.  I then copied the Xcode app to my Applications folder.  By doing that way, can I assume that it's already installed?

When I type "xcode" in Spotlight, it does see the Xcode app.

Your thoughts?

Comment: Can you edit this to show a link to the version of Xcode you are having problems with? If it's one only NDA cleared people can access, perhaps Stack Overflow would be a better place for this question. Have a look at the [faq] and let us know if this should be closed here. AFAIK, the App Store version of the program should solve your issue with installing a developer version and keep this on-topic here.

Comment: I'm not having problems with my Xcode.  I just want to know if I installed it correctly because I didn't go through the App store.  I opened the DMG file and then copied the Xcode app to my Applications folder and haven't seen some installation notes or progress.  So that' why I'm wondering. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a strange question to ask if you aren't experiencing any problems.

Yes, that's how you install Xcode when downloading from the developer centre.  However unless you need to run a beta version you're probably better off installing Xcode from the App Store, where you can benefit from update notifications and delta upgrades.

Comment: I didn't go to the App Store route because I didn't like the way it displays the progress of your download and I prefer to download using Safari so that I can see how many minutes remained in my download.  When using the App store, little did I know that my download was not working because I needed to register first in Apple's Developer site.

Comment: The App Store tells you time remaining on downloads as well.  You don't need a developer account to install Xcode from the App Store.

Comment: All I can see is just a progress bar on my Lion's Launchpad.  Where can I see the time indicator of the download?

Comment: Click the Purchases menu button.  You'll see a list of the applications you have installed, and when one is being installed/updated, there's a progress bar with time remaining.